# Persistent Integrity Constraint Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm still new to understanding relationships and the MVC. But I tried to follow everything I've read online and still receives this error.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`guest_log`.`logs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_guests1` FOREIGN KEY (`guest_id`) REFERENCES `guests` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Here is the SQL for guest, log and department

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Dept`;
CREATE TABLE `Dept` (
  `dept_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_code` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_description` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `dept_assign` enum('Academic','Admin') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Academic',
  `is_deleted` enum('Yes','No') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_id`)
)
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for guests
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guests`;
CREATE TABLE `guests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel_no` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_no` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for logs
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `logs`;
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `guest_id_number` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_time_in` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_time_out` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `purpose` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `department_to_visit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`guest_id`),
  KEY `fk_logs_guests1_idx` (`guest_id`),
  KEY `fk_logs_Dept1_idx` (`department_to_visit`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_guests1` FOREIGN KEY (`guest_id`) REFERENCES `guests` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_Dept1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_to_visit`) REFERENCES `Dept` (`dept_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

While here are the models.

```
class Guest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'guests';
    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Log');
    }
}

class Log extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'logs';
    public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Guest','guest_id','id');
    }
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department','department_to_visit','dept_id');
    }

}
class Department extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dept';
    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Log','department_to_visit','dept_id');
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to create a new entry for Log, I received this Integrity Constraint Violation error. Please help me resolved and understand why I'm encountering this problem.

UPDATE:

code to create log entry

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        {!! BootForm::inline(['route'=>['logs.store'],'method'=>'POST']) !!}

        {!! BootForm::select('guest_id', 'Guest Name',\App\Guest::pluck('last_name','id'),null, [])!!}


        {!! BootForm::tel('guest_id_number','ID Number',null, ['required']) !!}
        {!! BootForm::select('department_to_visit','Department to Visit', App\Department::pluck('dept_description','dept_id'),null,[]) !!}
        {!! BootForm::text('purpose',null,null,['required']) !!}

        {!! BootForm::submit('Save') !!}

        {!! BootForm::close() !!}


    </div>
```

log.store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'guest_id'=>'required',
        'guest_id_number'=>'required',
        'purpose'=>'required',
        'department_to_visit']);
    $logs = new Log();
    $logs->guest_id = $request->guest_id;
    $logs->guest_id_number = $request->guest_id_number;
    $logs->purpose = $request->purpose;
    $logs->department_to_visit = $request->department_to_visit;
    $logs->date_time_in = Carbon::now();
    $logs->save();
    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where are you trying to create the log entry?

Comment: @Peter i just updated with the code for creating

Comment: You code looks to be correct, and the error indicates that you are not providing a valid guest id. I would look to what is being passed in with your request and see if it actually matches any existing records.

Answer (score 0):

It could be you are not passing and existing guest id.
To check it normally I search the model, for eg.

```
$guest = Guest::findOrFail($request->guest_id);
```

and use

```
$logs->guest_id = $guest->id;
```

Try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: It works with the guest. but it didn't w ith the department. I tried this line for the department 
`   $department=Department::findOrFail($request->department_to_visit);
        $logs->department_to_visit = $department->dept_id;`

error is Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dept.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `dept` where `dept`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: It is because your department hasnt 'id' column like primary key. There are two way to resolve this. 1) `$department = Department::where('yourprimarykey',$request->department_to_visit')->first();` or declare in your departmet model de primary key  `protected $primaryKey='thefieldprimarykeyinyourtable';`

Comment: I received the same integrity constraint error both ways